# Android - No access to webservice when I run it on device, but with AVD it's working. Why?

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat, xmlpullparser

I have a webservice with this location:

`<wsdlsoap:address location="http://app.example.com:8080/WSTest/services/Hello"/>`

And I want to get access to this webservice over my Android app. I do this:

```
private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.audiomobil.com";
            private final String URL = "http://app.example.com:8080/WSTest/services/Hello?wsdl";
            private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.audiomobil.com/hello";
            private final String METHOD_NAME = "hello";

            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                String firstName = "Android";
                String lastName = "Program";
/*
                // Pass value for fname variable of the web service
                PropertyInfo fnameProp = new PropertyInfo();
                fnameProp.setName("fname");         // Define the variable name in the web service method
                fnameProp.setValue(firstName);      // Define value for fname variable
                fnameProp.setType(String.class);    // Define the type of thevariable
                request.addProperty(fnameProp);     // Pass properties to thevariable

                // Pass value for lname variable of the web service
                PropertyInfo lnameProp = new PropertyInfo();
                lnameProp.setName("lname");
                lnameProp.setValue(lastName);
                lnameProp.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(lnameProp);
*/
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                    String s = response.toString();
                    System.out.println("WS: " + s);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
```

**++++++EDIT**
My Webservice class is this:

```
public class Hello {
    public String hello(String fname, String lname){
         return "Hello";
     }
}
```

**+++++++**

When I run this on my **AVD Emulator** Android 4.0.3 then its working fine. Its get access to webservice and I get the response.

But when I run it on my device **Version 4.0.3**, then it's not working. It stops at this point: `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

And it throws a **XMLPullParserException**. Heres the logcat:

```
    01-23 11:24:36.959: I/System.out(8172): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 

unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @1:86 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4188c258)
```

I have really no idea how this can happen. Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Is the mobile internet on in the device when you're running this application?

Comment: yes the intnernet is on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the xml version tag. Try to set **xml version tag** before calling

```
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Sample Code:

```
public static String webServiceForScriptTimeLimit() {
        String scriptTimeLimitResponse = null;
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                    SCRIPT_TIMELIMIT_METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
            envelope.xsd = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
            envelope.xsi = SoapEnvelope.XSI;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            ht.debug = true;
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION_TIME_LIMIT, envelope);
            final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();
            scriptTimeLimitResponse = response.toString();

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            FileLog.logInfo(
                    "Exception ---> WS_ERROR ---> WebServiceUtility: webServiceForScriptTimeLimit() - "
                            + ex.toString(), 0);
        }
        return scriptTimeLimitResponse;
    }
```

Comment: no same exception :( .. I just dont understand why its working on the AVD and on device not more.

Comment: I think the xml format you are passing doesn't matches the web service param's. format may wrong

Comment: Do one thing just create xml tag with text in string buffer and pass.lets see whats happen

Comment: i dont know exactly what u mean?

Comment: you are using propertinfo, instead create your own string that should be in xml format and pass that to service

Comment: look my edit. I just return a String from the webservice. And I dont pass any values anymore. But it is still the same problem.

Comment: then the problem is with response i think

Comment: whats the SOAP_ACTION_TIME_LIMIT?

Comment: thx for your help. But now I've found the problem. Port 8080 was not open from extern, only from LAN. Our Administrator for the network opened another port so it was a really stupid problem to find out. But now it works. Thank u again for help.